# Как вытянуть оверлей из макета (psd)

Tags: вёрстка, frontend, веб-дизайн, photoshop

Имеется макет https://dropmefiles.com/PHfGJ у него имеется какая-то зернистость или градиент что ли. В общем вот, смотрю цвет в одном месте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в другом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как вытянуть этот оверлей для верстки.

Comment: что значит слово вытянуть? получить значения для градиента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача повторить то как-то так:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(48,55,65);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(48,55,65,1) 0%, rgba(47,55,65,1) 50%, rgba(48,55,65,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оно))) А как вы получили эти значения?